# Scrapy Error : Missing scheme in request url

Tags: scrapy, python-3.6, scrapinghub

I am facing issues with some urls while running scrappy

```
    ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: mailto:?body=https%3A%2F%2Fiview.abc.net.au%2Fshow%2Finsiders
[scrapy.core.scraper:168|ERROR] Spider error processing <GET https://iview.abc.net.au/show/four-corners/series/2020/video/NC2003H028S00> (referer: None)
```

Here are my settings:

```
"base_urls" : [
    {
      # Start crawling from 
      "url": "https://www.abc.net.au/",

      # Overwrite the default crawler and use th RecursiveCrawler instead
      "crawler": "RecursiveCrawler",
```

This works ok with following setting

```
"base_urls" : [
    {
      # Start crawling from 
      "url": "https://www.afr.com/",

      # Overwrite the default crawler and use th RecursiveCrawler instead
      "crawler": "RecursiveCrawler",
```

Not sure what I am missing here

Answer (score 1):

You have different behaviors because of the content beign scraped. The problem is that at some point your spider is trying to yield a Request for this URL:

```
mailto:?body=https%3A%2F%2Fiview.abc.net.au%2Fshow%2Finsiders
```

The correct URL is probably this:

```
https://iview.abc.net.au/show/insiders
```

It's possible that you are scraping the wrong field, or that there was a mistake in the site where this "url" is retrieved.